# TextView wont show as bold

Tags: java, android, xml, textview

the text in my TextView doesn't show in bold styling in run-time even after i set the flag on the XML to true, in all phone emulators/real phone debugging
this is the code:

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="171dp"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="152dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="208dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:text="@string/enterDns"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        android:textColor="@color/txtDefault"
        android:textSize="26sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="normal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

important to say there is no other manipulation of the text in my code, only XML preset.

Comment: I think the `android:textAppearance` might interfere here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:textAppearance

Comment: @QBrute is right. You ovverride your textStyle property with setting textApparance.

Comment: still without any visible change, might there a way to make the style of the text look even bolder?

Answer (score 0):

Remove  `android:textAppearance` It's work fine

```
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="171dp"
            android:layout_height="37dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="152dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="208dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:gravity="start"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:text="@string/enterDns"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="26sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="normal" />
```

Comment: still without any visible change, might there a way to make the style of the text look even bolder?

Comment: Simply you have to write android:textStyle="bold"